# Neo4j self created certificates does not match

Tags: ssl, neo4j

I have a Neo4j cluster which contains two data instances and one arbiter.

We've installed self signed certificates on both servers and places them in `/var/lib/neo4j/certificates` folder.

I'm querying the cluster with `neo4j-driver` (python) and using a DNS route as the host URL. The DNS redirects into my data servers.

In some cases I receive the following error:
`Server certificate does not match known certificate for 'some-address'; check details in file '/home/wsgi/.neo4j/known_hosts'`

How can I check which certificate are the servers really using?

Thank you,
Maya

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I was using an old version of the driver which had "TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE" trust policy. This policy has been deprecated and after upgrading the package this problem cannot happen again.